# TCPDF SYMFONY BUNDLE error wihle creating multiple pdf files

Tags: symfony, tcpdf

I m trying to create PDF files in Symfony using TCPDF bundle.
While creating single file, it works properly.

But Fails while creating multiple files.

```
Error:Notice: Undefined property: Io\TcpdfBundle\Helper\Tcpdf::$h
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating a new TCPDF object for subsequent files or reusing the same object?

Comment: Was using the same object. Changed it. Thanks.